# How to re-order array elements if there is a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

It seems Wordpress wp_query doesn't provide an option of order by post_status. And I want to list private posts before other posts. The posts array looks like this:

```
$posts = array(
             0=>object{
                     ....
                },
             1=>object{
                     ....
               },
            ....
         );
```

Each post object has a key of 'post_status'. I want to move the post to the beginning of the array if the value is 'private', . How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($posts, ($a, $b) {
    return ($a->post_status < $b->post_status) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [uasort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).
This allows you to write your own comparison function and sort the array as you need it.